# C#: Hide Login Form after successful login

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (emailTextBox.Text == "abc" && passwordTextBox.Text == "password123")
    {
        MainForm f1 = new MainForm();
        f1.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email or Password.");
    }
}
```

I have this login form that whenever I give the correct login info, another form will show but I cannot get the login form to close. I have tried doing

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Hide();
```

But that does not work.

Comment: Where and how do you create your login form? What do you call it, is it called f2?

Comment: You are hiding a new instance of the form, not the form that is already open.

Comment: The login form is named Form2. MainForm is my application that users should see after logging in

Comment: Can the login form not close itself? After `f1.Show();` call `Close();`.

Comment: Just tried using Close(); and now both forms close

Comment: If `Close()` is in the main form, this closes the application. You can also call `Hide();` instead. By "main form" I mean the form which is started at the application start.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (emailTextBox.Text == "abc" && passwordTextBox.Text == "password123")
    {
        MainForm f1 = new MainForm();
        f1.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email or Password.");
    }
```

Comment: This worked! I forgot to mention I also tried this.Close(); but that didn't work either. Why does .Hide(); work and not Close();?

Comment: Hide() doesn't dispose the form instance which is why the application keeps running, on the other hand Close() sends a message to close the windows dialog and when a form is closed all resources created within that form are disposed which is why both the login form and the instance of the MainForm are disposed when Close() is used.